# When do you put a comma after the last word or thing in a long list followed by a verb and object?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, commas, lists, intonation

When do you put a comma after the last word or thing
in a long list followed by a verb and object?  This
question in the context of a novel is about the last
or terminal comma after a long list that transitions
into a verb and object.

Does the last thing or word in a list have a comma
after it, when the following verb applies to
everything in the list? Whereas the last thing or
word in the list does not have a comma after it, when
the following verb just applies to the last thing in
the list? Is this true? If not, then what is the rule?
Does the comma only indicate a pause? So is it
arbitrary or personal preference of where you want a
pause in the text?

For example:

1. [...] with his head facing forward, back hunched over, and hips swiveled **upwards, so** that the back of his knees on his shoulders [...]
2. [...] with his head facing forward, back hunched over, and hips swiveled **upwards so** that the back of his knees rest on his shoulders [...]
3. Salmon, barracuda, tarpon, seals, whales, goldfish, and **sharks, swim** regularly.
4. Salmon, barracuda, tarpon, seals, whales, goldfish, and **sharks swim** regularly.

Are these two sentences and their alternatives interchangeable, or is
there a difference implied by the final comma? Or is the only difference
that the last comma in #1 and #3 indicates a pause after upwards
and sharks?

Comment: The examples are not alike enough. I'm feeling 1 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

- I'd say (3) and (4) are interchangeable. My preference is for the less cluttered (4).
- But (1) and (2) default to different readings in my opinion.
- (1) … [with his head facing forward, back hunched over, and hips swivelled upwards], so that the back of his knees on his shoulders …

(3 contributing factors in cause prepositional string) but

- (2) … with his head facing forward, back hunched over, and [hips swivelled upwards so that the back of his knees on his shoulders …]

(just one contributing factor).

Answer (score 0):

I believe questions 1 and 3 are the preferable form.  Let's see if I can articulate my reasoning.  In questions 2 and 4, the final comma appears to completely separate the clause that follows, from the other things/conditions etc in the list.  The object contained within that clause then seems to carry a heavier weight in relation to the items in the list.  In contrast, in examples 1 and 3, the items listed appear to all have the same importance in relation to the verb that follows the final comma.

Comment: Please note that even though this answer has been accepted, it is not correct. Sentence 3 includes a comma between the complete subject and complete predicate, which is almost always considered an error.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Oh okay, that is helpful. Thank you to you both.

Answer (score 0):

All are OK but numbers 1 and 3 are my choices. In Warner's English Grammar the last comma of a list is optional. As a matter of taste and usage I have always left it off, probably since that is the usage I see the most.